# SQL Group by and having in coherence

Tags: caching, oracle-coherence

I would like to execute the following query in Coherence

```
Select AVG(Salary)
     , Count(*)
from Employees
group by Company
Having AVG(Salary)> 1000
```

I was trying to use GroupAggregators but I have problem with refering to an avarage salary as it is not defined in the Employee Class but in Aggregator:

```
GroupAggregator high_salary = GroupAggregator.createInstance("getDepartment"
                                                  , new DoubleAverage("getSalary")
                                                  , new GreaterFilter("DoubleAverage", 1000));
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `IdentityExtractor.INSTANCE` instead of `"DoubleAverage"` as a value extractor in `GreaterFilter`, because value passed to this filter is the avarage salary itself, not some object with "DoubleAverage" property.

But if you would like to get avarage salary as well as count (that would be consistent with your SQL query), you will have to use `CompositeAggregator`. In that case the value passed to the filter will not be a number anymore, but a `List` and you will have to use `ValueExtractor` that will extract avarage salary from this list. In Coherence 12.2.1 it would look like this:

```java
    DoubleAverage<Employee> avgSalary = new DoubleAverage<>(Employee::getSalary);
    Count<String, Employee> count = new Count<>();

    CompositeAggregator<String, Country> compositeAggregator = CompositeAggregator
            .createInstance(new InvocableMap.EntryAggregator[] { avgSalary, count });

    ValueExtractor<Object, ? extends Double> salaryExtractor = 
            list -> ((List<Number>) list).get(0).doubleValue();
    Filter having = Filters.greater(salaryExtractor, 1000.0);
    GroupAggregator<String, Country, Employee, String, List> groupAggregator = 
            GroupAggregator.createInstance(Employee::getDepartment, compositeAggregator, having);
```

It can be done also in older versions, but it would require some more work to implement `salaryExtractor` without using lambda expression.